# How can I use 'Viewable' in Jersey Framework?

Tags: jsp, frameworks, jersey, web.xml

I developed using jersey framework.This program has two functions.

JSON Communication Function and JSP Calling Function.
However, only JSON Function works.

JSP file located this path.

> .../WEB-INF/views/myJSP.jsp

And, URL is ..

> JSP Function  : http://{host}:{port}/proj/myClass/FuncJSON
>
> JSON Function : http://{host}:{port}/proj/myClass/FuncJSP

It is my web.xml

```
<!-- for FuncJSP -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>funcjsp</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>proj.com.compony.proj.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath
        </param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/views/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex
        </param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/views/.*</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>funcjsp</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/proj/myClass/funcJSP/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- for FuncJSON -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>funcjson</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>proj.com.compony.proj.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>funcjson</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/proj/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It is my source.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/FuncJSON")
public String funcJSON(JSONObject jsonObject, @Context HttpServletRequest req,  @Context HttpServletResponse res) {
    ...
    log.debug("** funcJSON **");
}


@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Path("/FuncJSP")
public Viewable funcJSP(
        @Context HttpServletRequest req,
        @Context HttpServletResponse res) {
    ...
    log.debug("** funcJSP **");
    return new Viewable("/myJSP.jsp");
}
```

If I execute FuncJSP,
"** funcJSP **" recorded in log file.

However, result view is "No data was received(Chrome)".

Please give me some advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a different mapping and see if it works first:

instead of:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>funcjsp</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/proj/myClass/funcJSP/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

use:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>funcjsp</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/myClass/funcJSP/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```